# Mysqli for PHP in package mysql

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql

I am trying to get mysqli set up for php5 but apt tries to substitute `php5-mysql` for `php5-mysqli`, which doesn't exist.  Does the mysql package also carry the mysqli extension, or do I need to find the source and compile it somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the description of the package `php5-mysql`(version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2) :

> This package provides modules for MySQL database connections directly from
>   PHP scripts.  It includes the generic "mysql" module which can be used
>   to connect to all versions of MySQL, **an improved "mysqli" module for
>   MySQL version 4.1 or later**, and the pdo_mysql module for use with
>   the PHP Data Object extension.

So, the package `php5-mysql` does contain support for MYSQLi extension.

Comment: I didn't see the description on [Ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com) for some reason.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS So, sometimes GUI tools like synaptic can be useful over command line tools, too. :)

Comment: I wasn't using a command-line, I was looking on the website.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS Please don't mind, that comment wasn't specifically targeted to you, it's just my expression, because I myself use `apt-get` most of the time unless I really have to read the description of an available package.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to clarify. Also, should we need another comment for some reason, I suggest moving to chat.